# Why two float divs are standing one under another?

Tags: html, css

Why is the second div going under the first? Both of them are "float" elements. When I set a width of the second div, all works well. But I expect these two divs are being located to one row.

```css
.one {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.two {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Menu</div>
<div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto beatae delectus eveniet impedit, labore minima nihil nostrum sint voluptates. Animi illum minima officia placeat quo rem repellendus reprehenderit vel.</div>
```

Comment: You need to define widths for both of floating elements otherwise in case of increase in content of any of the floating divs will result in drop of one div below the other.

Comment: This is because you didn't define the width's of the floating elements.

Comment: All you need here is clearfix https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: I would of used `inline-block` if your trying to get them to stay on one line. Also apply a width to the second `div`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you didn't define the width's of the floating elements. If you define a `max-width`, say `50%`, they will no longer be on the same line. I recommend giving `max-width` in contrast to `width` because, I believe you don't want to give the elements, a static `width`. Plus, they should be flexible to take as much as space they want, unless they shouldn't mess up with one another, which happens after `50%`.

```css
.one {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.two {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 50%;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Menu</div>
<div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto beatae delectus eveniet impedit, labore minima nihil nostrum sint voluptates. Animi illum minima officia placeat quo rem repellendus reprehenderit vel.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex instead float.
Add `display: flex;` for a container. And `flex: 0 0 auto;` for the first div and `flex: 1 1 auto;` for the second. `flex: 0 0 auto;` means that element will take as much space as needed. `flex: 1 1 auto;` means that element will take all available space.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.one {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">Menu</div>
  <div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto beatae delectus eveniet impedit, labore minima nihil nostrum sint voluptates. Animi illum minima officia placeat quo rem repellendus reprehenderit vel.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You still didn't answer the question of why it happens. But yea, nice alternate solution, working only on modern browsers.

Comment: It's time to forget about old browsers =)

Comment: Be aware that this ****ty banks still use IE 6! `:P`

Answer (score 0):

You can just give them some width options in %, or pixels using calc CSS functions, something like this...

```css
.one {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
}
.two {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Menu</div>
<div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto beatae delectus eveniet impedit, labore minima nihil nostrum sint voluptates. Animi illum minima officia placeat quo rem repellendus reprehenderit vel.</div>
```

Comment: Don't encourage `calc` functions, as they are not performant.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is what you really want I think, float is great but always felt like a hack as opposed to a real solution.

You can use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) across all browsers, IE8 can't handle it but that's not a supported browser anymore. I suggest you read up on it on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) they generally have quite nice tutorials.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.one,
.two {
  padding: 5px;
}
.one {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.two {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="one">Menu</div>
  <div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto beatae delectus eveniet impedit, labore minima nihil nostrum sint voluptates. Animi illum minima officia placeat quo rem repellendus reprehenderit vel.</div>
</div>
```

As to why it's was happening with float, unless you say otherwise anything display block will take up the entire space allotted, which is 100%, with one of the divs taking up 100% there is no room for the other one on the same line.

You could have given it a set width, or changed the display to inline and removed the float left from .two (though that would have been a little odd looking).

```css
.one {
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.two {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Menu</div>
<div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto beatae delectus eveniet impedit, labore minima nihil nostrum sint voluptates. Animi illum minima officia placeat quo rem repellendus reprehenderit vel.</div>
```